# take photo in cordova with input type="file"

Tags: html, cordova

How do i get HTML5 `capture` attribute supported on cordova application. I am looking for a cordova polyfill (if i may say so) for capture attribute.

I basically want camera(to take photo) to come up as an option for `input type="file"` like it happens on mobile web.

Comment: Input type="file" not support on mobile web.

Comment: @HanhLe, of course input type="file" is supported on mobile web. aWebDeveloper, there is no polyfill, input type file on android won't let you choose the camera. You can use the camera plugin instead.

Comment: can i make camera and input file return datauri